# Why is BSS not increasing under the presence of a global static variable?

Tags: c

I am running on a 64-bit Windows system and currently trying to learn C. The codes are given below.

**Code 1**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
}
```

Size:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   9724    2200    2432   14356    3814 main.exe
```

**Code 2**

```
#include<stdio.h>

static int i;
int main() {
}
```

Size:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   9724    2200    2432   14356    3814 main.exe
```

Comment: Maybe it's padded to some multiple and the int fits within the padding. Alternatively the compiler might remove the unused variable

Comment: You should be able to output the linker map (using some linker option) which will show the offset and size of each item within bss

Comment: It's also possible that the compiler is optimizing it away, since it is unreferenced.

Comment: What compiler and options?

Comment: Maybe assign a value to the variable and inspect the contents of the sections using some tool (i dont know whats the windows equivalent of objdump)? Also there should be a symbol table in the file, maybe it will tell you where is "i" stored?